# How do you plot histogram of very high and low frequency counts in matplotlib?

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, histogram, probability-density

I have a data as follows :

```
data = [4, 10, 3, 4, 3, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 3, 3, 4, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 2, 7, 1, 1, 3, 3, 1, 3, 1, 1, 1, 58, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 5, 2, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 3, 3, 1, 2, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 3, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 11, 1, 5, 1, 6, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 4, 1, 1, 7, 3, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 2, 6, 1, 2, 1, 1, 2, 1, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 22, 5, 1, 1, 1, 3, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 12, 1, 99, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 3, 1, 1, 1, 1, 44, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 3, 25, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 10, 1, 5, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 3, 12, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 4, 7, 1, 1, 2, 1, 56, 1, 4, 12, 2, 1, 1, 4, 1, 1, 1, 2, 3, 1, 1, 5, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 6, 1, 1, 4, 1, 1, 1, 1, 3, 1, 1, 23, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 3, 10, 1, 1, 1, 1, 5, 3, 2, 1, 3, 3, 1, 1, 1, 29, 1, 2, 2, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 3, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 3, 1, 1, 1, 11, 1, 3, 1, 2, 14, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 38, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 3, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 1, 1, 3, 1, 1, 4, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 14, 1, 1, 1, 5, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 2, 2, 1, 3, 1, 1, 1, 1, 3, 1, 4, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 5, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 12, 2, 64, 1, 1, 3, 1, 11, 5, 1, 1, 1, 1, 3, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 2, 2, 1, 3, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 62, 1, 1, 1, 2, 5, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 1, 2, 1, 1, 2, 1, 7, 2, 1, 1, 1, 5, 12, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 9, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 17, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 5, 2, 4, 1, 1, 1, 8, 3, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 3, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 5, 1, 1, 9, 2, 1, 2, 1, 1, 6, 1, 1, 6, 7, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 3, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 21, 82, 1, 1, 3, 1, 2, 42, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 6, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 6, 1, 2, 1, 2, 2, 1, 2, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 7, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 4, 1, 1, 1, 4, 1, 1, 1, 1, 4, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 3, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 7, 55, 2, 1, 1, 4, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 4, 1, 2, 1, 1, 32, 31, 1, 2, 1, 3, 2, 1, 1, 1, 8, 1, 1, 6, 1, 1, 20, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 4, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 15, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 3, 8, 1, 2, 1, 3, 1, 1, 2, 3, 1, 6, 1, 3, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 3, 4, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 23, 1, 1, 1, 2, 5, 1, 558, 1, 1, 1, 1, 5, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 2, 6, 5, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 14, 1, 1, 3, 1, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 77, 1, 6, 36, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 8, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 13, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 67, 1, 2, 3, 1, 14, 3, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 11, 1, 3, 4, 1, 25, 1, 1, 1, 3, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 3, 1, 4, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 14, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 7, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 3, 1, 1, 1, 3, 1, 1, 1, 1, 5, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 22, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 5, 1, 1, 1, 6, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 9, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 2, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 4, 4, 3, 1, 1, 1, 11, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 6, 1, 80, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 12, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 11, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 2, 16, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 3, 1, 1, 1, 4, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 3, 1, 2, 11, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 4, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 45, 4, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 4, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 16, 3, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 3, 3, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 7, 1, 2, 1, 3, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 3, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 6, 1, 1, 5, 1, 3, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 3, 1, 1, 31, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 3, 5, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 4, 2, 6, 8, 1, 4, 10, 1, 1, 1, 4, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 8, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 33, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 1, 1, 3, 1, 1, 2, 7, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 2, 3, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 8, 4, 1, 10, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 3, 1, 18, 2, 1, 5, 1, 2, 1, 1, 3, 1, 1, 3, 1, 4, 1, 5, 1, 1, 6, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 9, 3, 23, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 4, 1, 1, 1, 3, 1, 2, 1, 1, 4, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1705, 2, 1, 5, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 29, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 2, 1, 30, 1, 5, 2, 1, 3, 2, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 6, 2, 1, 4, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 6, 1, 6, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 2, 7, 1, 2, 1, 2, 4, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 6, 1, 1, 1, 2, 3, 1492, 4, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 22, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 23, 327, 1, 1, 1, 29, 1, 8, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 8, 1, 1, 1, 1, 7, 6, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 8, 3, 3, 2, 1, 1, 4, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 14, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 3, 2, 4, 2, 3, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 3, 2, 1, 1, 3, 51, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 3, 1, 13, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 28, 1, 1, 1, 15, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 4, 1, 1, 1, 1, 7, 1, 1, 1, 1, 4, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 3, 1, 2, 11, 1, 6, 2, 3, 1, 1, 1, 2, 3, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 3, 1, 1, 1, 1, 5, 1, 1, 6, 1, 2, 3, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 6, 1, 18, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 3, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 5, 1, 1, 3, 1, 3, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 30, 1, 1, 1, 1, 3, 1, 3, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 218, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 5, 1, 29, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 13, 1, 3, 1, 1, 15, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 4, 5, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 6, 3, 11, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 5, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 9, 3, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 17, 1, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 21, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 14, 1, 1, 1, 1, 7, 4, 4, 6, 1, 1, 1, 3, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 3, 1, 1, 6, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 10, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 4, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 3, 9, 7, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 3, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 9, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 4, 2, 2, 32, 2, 15, 1, 1, 1, 3, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 6, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 15020, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 6, 1, 1, 1, 2, 68, 1, 1, 1, 1, 3, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 8, 4, 1, 3, 10, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 6, 1, 1, 1, 17, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 3, 1, 1, 1, 1, 3, 1, 5, 8, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 23, 3, 1, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 3, 1, 1, 1, 22, 2, 1, 2, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 4, 12, 1, 1, 1, 3, 1, 1, 1, 3, 1, 1, 2, 1, 5, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 8, 406, 1, 16, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 10, 1, 20, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 17, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 4, 1, 1, 9, 1, 1, 4, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 4, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 25, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 17, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 2, 6, 2, 12, 1, 7, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 58, 3, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 3, 1, 1, 1, 4, 1, 1, 11, 1, 3, 3, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 6, 2, 12, 1, 1, 1, 4, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 126, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 3, 1, 26, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 3, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 277, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 4, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 20, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 48, 16, 1, 2, 1, 1, 2, 1, 16, 1, 14, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 3, 1, 5, 1, 2, 8, 3, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 14, 1, 4, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 4, 18, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 3, 1, 1, 1, 6, 1, 1, 1, 1, 3, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 5, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 4, 1, 9, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 5, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 39, 1, 1, 1, 1, 3, 1, 1, 12, 1, 1, 1, 1, 5, 1, 22, 1, 1, 3, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 19, 3, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 4, 1, 3, 1, 2, 3, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 9, 1, 1, 3, 2, 1, 1, 8, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 5, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 3, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 2, 14, 1, 1, 2, 1, 89, 1, 3, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 37, 14, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 211, 1, 2, 1, 5, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 6, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 4, 5, 4, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 3, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 21, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 3, 12, 1, 5, 1, 1, 10, 1, 21, 1, 5, 1, 1, 2, 2, 1, 2, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 5, 5, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 7, 1, 8, 1, 1, 5, 1, 1, 1, 1, 3, 1, 3, 1, 1, 1, 14, 1, 1, 3, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 4, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 67, 2, 4, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 3, 1, 4, 3, 7, 6, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 2, 3, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 3, 3, 1, 3, 1, 3, 3, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 4, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 6, 1, 17, 12, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 5, 5, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 292, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 33, 1, 1, 1, 1, 14, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 4, 1, 3, 2, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 9, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 3, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 5, 1, 1, 1, 9, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 26, 4, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 36, 1, 1, 1, 1, 5, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 5, 1, 3, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 3, 17, 1, 1, 3, 2, 1, 1, 1, 8, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 13, 1, 1, 1, 1, 7, 1, 1, 1, 39, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 47, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 31, 1, 14, 5, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 5, 1, 1, 18, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 14, 1, 1, 3, 1, 2, 11, 2, 3, 3, 6, 1, 1, 3, 2, 1, 1, 1, 3, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 3, 1, 4, 3, 1, 5, 1, 3, 1, 5, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 176, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 3, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 5, 1, 8, 1, 1, 3, 1, 1, 3, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 4, 1, 1, 1, 8, 4, 2, 2, 1, 21, 4, 1, 1, 21, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 3, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 5, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 1, 2, 1, 1, 2, 2, 1, 1, 11, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 7, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 12, 1, 3, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 909, 1, 1, 6, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 4, 1, 6, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 4, 1, 3, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 78, 2, 2, 1, 1, 10, 2, 1, 1, 1, 6, 1, 1, 1, 4, 15, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 4, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 3, 1, 4, 2, 2, 4, 3, 4, 2, 1, 3, 4, 2, 1, 1, 17, 2, 1, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 11, 1, 1, 8, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 4, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 3, 3, 1, 25, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 3, 1, 2, 1, 15, 1, 1, 3, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 4, 1, 33, 1, 1, 1, 1, 3, 1, 1, 7, 7, 3, 1, 1, 6, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 13, 2, 3, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 14, 4, 4, 3, 1, 1, 53, 1, 1, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 4, 1, 1, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 7, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 9, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 19, 3, 1, 3, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 3, 1, 4, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 7, 3, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 8, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 4, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 16, 26, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 190, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 4, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 6, 1, 1, 2, 210, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 2, 1, 4, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]
```

When I plot the Histogram in matplotlib of this data, It shows me a single Bar, that's because of such a high value 15020 and low value 1 with high frequency. I want to plot the PDF ( Probability density function ) and Histogram for the data, how can I do this?[Plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fBNRP.png)

Comment: you have to use a logarithmic y-scale ...

Comment: and you can 'remove'  the one before plotting: `l=np.log(np.array(l));l=l[np.nonzero(l)]`

Comment: and also x logarithmic ...

Comment: I would notice you only have 27% of non-1 value in your original data. So better remove them and plot the log-log to have a vision on the rest repartition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I took your data and wrote code around it. I did observe that since your data list contains 3551 numbers, its not possible to show on single line. 
Solution:
1) use `\` periodically so that IDE doesn't get overwhelmed
2) Transfer data to a file and read data from that file.

Detailed examples are available [here](http://matplotlib.org/1.2.1/examples/pylab_examples/histogram_demo.html)

**Demo Code**

I transferred your data to `mydata.text` file and read from that.
Here is a working code.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

aList= []
for i in open('myData.txt').read().split():
    aList.append(i.rstrip(','))

myData = map(int, aList)
plt.plot(myData)
plt.ylabel('Frequncy [ Hz]')
plt.xlabel('Number of Freq')
plt.show()
```

**Graph**
[image]

Comment: What's on the X axis and Y axis? How do I read this plot? I'll have to put labels on both the axes.

Comment: Y axis is Frequency value as per your data and X axis is number of freq as per your data. You will notice as you have 3551 count of freq in data , the X axis starts  starts at 1 and ends at 4000 with last bar at 3551. I don't know if you want values in linear or log scale. Above graph is in linear scale. If you want in log ,you will need to convert to log scale as others have indicated.

Comment: You can use plt.xlabel('your x label ') to label x axis . I updated code to reflect that

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
superlist = [1,2,3,4]
plt.plot(superlist)
plt.ylabel('some numbers')
plt.show()
```

Source:
[1](http://matplotlib.org/users/pyplot_tutorial.html)